# Prevent dialog from going off screen

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a primaryStage which is fine.  I have a dialog that opens fine centered on the primaryStage (I got this to work by making the owner to the dialog the primaryStage

```
dialog.setInitOwner(primaryStage).
```

However, the dialog will go off-screen if the primaryStage is already close to the edge of the screen. How do I make the dialog (which has the primaryStage as the owner) not go off the screen if the owner is near the edge of the screen?

I've tried this:

```
    double x = dialog.getX();
    double y = dialog.getY();
    double w = dialog.getWidth();
    double h = dialog.getHeight();
    if (x < Main.bounds.getMinX())
    {
        dialog.setX(Main.bounds.getMinX());
    }
    if (x + w > Main.bounds.getMaxX())
    {
        dialog.setX(Main.bounds.getMaxX() - w);
    }
    if (y < Main.bounds.getMinY())
    {
        dialog.setY(Main.bounds.getMinY());
    }
    if (y + h > Main.bounds.getMaxY())
    {
        dialog.setY(Main.bounds.getMaxY() - h);
    }

    dialog.showAndWait();
```

Main.bounds is created by:

```
private static Bounds computeAllScreenBounds()
{
    double minX = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double minY = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double maxX = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    double maxY = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreens())
    {
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
        if (screenBounds.getMinX() < minX)
        {
            minX = screenBounds.getMinX();
        }
        if (screenBounds.getMinY() < minY)
        {
            minY = screenBounds.getMinY();
        }
        if (screenBounds.getMaxX() > maxX)
        {
            maxX = screenBounds.getMaxX();
        }
        if (screenBounds.getMaxY() > maxY)
        {
            maxY = screenBounds.getMaxY();
        }
    }
    return new BoundingBox(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
```

Trying this, doesn't change any behaviour. I feel it's because the dialog.getX() function returns a NaN...
    }

As requested, an example:

```
public class Test extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Bounds bounds = computeAllScreenBounds();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText("This is an alert!");
                alert.setContentText("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
                double x = alert.getX();
                double y = alert.getY();
                double w = alert.getWidth();
                double h = alert.getHeight();
                if (x < bounds.getMinX())
                {
                    alert.setX(bounds.getMinX());
                }
                if (x + w > bounds.getMaxX())
                {
                    alert.setX(bounds.getMaxX() - w);
                }
                if (y < bounds.getMinY())
                {
                    alert.setY(bounds.getMinY());
                }
                if (y + h > bounds.getMaxY())
                {
                    alert.setY(bounds.getMaxY() - h);
                }
                alert.showAndWait();

            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static Bounds computeAllScreenBounds()
    {
        double minX = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double minY = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        double maxX = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        double maxY = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        for (Screen screen : Screen.getScreens())
        {
            Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
            if (screenBounds.getMinX() < minX)
            {
                minX = screenBounds.getMinX();
            }
            if (screenBounds.getMinY() < minY)
            {
                minY = screenBounds.getMinY();
            }
            if (screenBounds.getMaxX() > maxX)
            {
                maxX = screenBounds.getMaxX();
            }
            if (screenBounds.getMaxY() > maxY)
            {
                maxY = screenBounds.getMaxY();
            }
        }
        return new BoundingBox(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
    }
}
```

Another ex:

```
public class Test extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setHeaderText("This is an alert!");
                alert.setContentText("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
                alert.setOnShown(new EventHandler<DialogEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DialogEvent event)
                    {

                        double x = alert.getX();
                        double y = alert.getY();
                        double w = alert.getWidth();
                        double h = alert.getHeight();

                        //SHOWS ALL NaN NaN NaN NaN
                        System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + w + " " + h);

                    }
                });
                alert.showAndWait();

            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I don't see how this problem would be happening.

Comment: When are you calling this code? If it's before the `Dialog` has been shown then you won't get the correct values (e.g. `NaN`) since the `Dialog` has not been positioned yet.

Comment: So how do I intercept it before that time? Also, added an example

Comment: Use `setOnShown` (see [marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52063102/6395627)). You can then call `setX`, `setY`, `setWidth`, and `setHeight` on the `Dialog` as necessary.

Comment: if you println the x and y of the dialog when in "setOnShown" it still says NaN

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior (for both Java 8 and Java 10). Attempting to get the `x`/`y`/`width`/`height` of the `Dialog` gives me real values when called inside the `onShown` handler.

Comment: I've added another copy-paste example... it does say NaN ...

Comment: It appears using `showAndWait()` causes the issue. I was using `show()`. If you need to use `showAndWait()` then it seems wrapping the code inside the `onShown` handler in a `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` call works around the problem.

Comment: @Slaw good catch :) as always, very reluctant to use runlater: the exact time of being processed is unspecified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (unexpected for me) problem with the onShown handler on the alert  when using showAndWait is that at the time the handler is invoked the alert is not yet showing and not yet sized/located - which is somewhat crazy and probably might be considered a bug.

A way around is to listen to the showingProperty of the alert and do any size/location adjustments in that listener. Something like (just a poc, obviously)

```
alert.showingProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
    double x = alert.getX();
    double y = alert.getY();
    double w = alert.getWidth();
    double h = alert.getHeight();

    // as example just adjust if location top/left is off 
    // production must cope with bottom/right off as well, obviously 
    if (x < 0) {
        alert.setWidth(w + x);
        alert.setY(0);
    }
    if (y <0) {
        alert.setHeight(h + y);
        alert.setY(0);
    }

});
alert.showAndWait();
```

---

FYI: I really think it's a bug, so filed an [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210214) let's see what happens

Comment: Thanks, I was able to add the code in my question in there, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: kleopatra, the issue in the link that you filed doesn't seem to be related to the onShown handler, but a combobox? is this right?

Comment: @trilogy mixed up issues - thanks for the heads up :) edited with correct link

Answer (score 1):

As you are positioning the dialog in the center of the stage.. the dialog could only be out of the screen if the stage is also (at least partly) outside of your screen.

Please see the following code example..

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 500);

    Button button = new Button("Alert");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText("This is an alert!");
            alert.initOwner(stage);

            alert.setOnShown(new EventHandler<DialogEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(DialogEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(alert.getOwner().getX());
                    System.out.println(alert.getOwner().getY());

                    //Values from screen
                    int screenMaxX = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getMaxX();
                    int screenMaxY = (int) Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getMaxY();

                    //Values from stage
                    int width = (int) stage.getWidth();
                    int height = (int) stage.getHeight();
                    int stageMaxX = (int) stage.getX();
                    int stageMaxY = (int) stage.getY();

                    //Maximal values your stage
                    int paneMaxX = screenMaxX - width;
                    int paneMaxY = screenMaxY - height;

                    //Check if the position of your stage is not out of screen 
                    if (stageMaxX > paneMaxX || stageMaxY > paneMaxY) {
                        //Set stage where ever you want
                    }
                }
            });

            alert.showAndWait();

        }
    });

    pane.getChildren().add(button);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried this yet, but the dialog goes off-screen partly because it's quite large to begin with. So even if the parent is not off-screen to begin with, the dialog can still go off-screen based on the size of it.

Comment: I guess you can use the same logic for that. When showing the alert.. Just check if the alert is out of screen and re-position it wherever the alert should be.

Comment: Just use stage.getX() and stage.getY() to re-position the stage. These methods could also be applied to the alert.

Comment: no, owner window not being centered is not the only way: if the alert is too large it still is partly off the screen - your solution does centers the dialog such that now it is off at both sides ;)